# keeping reference to dom nodes : memory concerns

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am building an online text editor type application (with many more functionality).

The application needs a lot of dom nodes lookup(for para update etc) in the dom and updating the node. The user may do a lot of operations on each nodes so I thought to permanently keep a reference to nodes instead of getElementById...etc.

I was thinking that as the number of dom nodes increases so will the references in my script.

1. What will be the memory impact of going this way?
2. More precisely the references that are kept in memory, are they simple references
   or bring along some heavy meta data?

Thanks.

Please ask questions if the problem is not clear.

Comment: Could you give an example of these operations, I'm just thinking that the `this` var on events or event delegation would be best. What would a "node" be and what actions which don't originate from said node would edit it?

Comment: for example i have 10 paragraphs in the editor and the user can update by typing, move the para up and down(to change order), delete or style it by various clicking various buttons. and now if i tend to keep the reference of each para node so that i can handle all these ops without having to lookup the dom again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so to make things clear and concrete, here is what i did. I added a button to a heavy stackoverflow page via console.

my btn = document.createElement('button');

and then on each click of the button I added a reference to document.body like this:

mybtn.onclick = function(){ myar=[]; for(var i=0;i<10000;i++){ myar[i]=document.body;}}

I performed many clicks and noted that there is a memory increase of about 0.5 MB per 10000 references being created.

Then I replaced the document.body with an empty object {}.

and again the memory increase is about 0.5 MB per 10000 references.

So we can safely conclude that references to dom node are still simple references and will not impact memory unless created excessively.

PS : I did the memory profiling with chrome memory timeline.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is call-by-sharing, see [Wikipédia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing), so it's only references, no metadatas.

I don't think the memory impact would be too big as long as you're not storing a crazy number of objects.